# How do I display an icon with `notify-send`?

Tags: release-odin, icons, notifications, bash, script

If I run `notify-send --icon=address-book-new "My notification"` the notification that comes up has an "info" icon:

[image: Notification]

And if I look at the notification in the notification popover, the notification has the right icon:

[image: Notification in notification popover]

How can I make it so the icon I specify is shown when the notification is first displayed, and not only when I view the notification popover?